# cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget does not work in dealloc

Tags: iphone, selector, dealloc

```
-(IBAction)voiceBroadcast
{

    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    }


    else {
        if (nil != audioPlayer) {
            [audioPlayer play];
            audioPlayer.volume = 0.0;
            [self performSelector:@selector(doBgMusicFadeIn)];
            [self performSelector:@selector(doBgMusicFadeDown) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
            [self performSelector:@selector(startVoiceBroadcast) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];

        }
    }
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    //position
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

    [super dealloc];

}
```

The `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self` in **`dealloc`** is called, but does not work, the selectors still be called. But `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self` in **`voiceBroadcast`** have no problem. Does the `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` method could not be used in **`dealloc`**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If you are using UIViewController...*

I don't know why isn't it executed, but you can try putting

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

in **`-viewDidUnload`** method, which is called before dealloc.

More info in [UIViewController's reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: It does not work, for this method "[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self] is not executed. But thank you for your help after all.

Comment: maybe theese methods (`-dealloc`, `-viewDidUnload`) are not being executed? Put some NSLogs in there and tell me if there is some output in the console.

Comment: dealloc is executed, and cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self in dealloc is executed too, but it does not work. The viewDidUnload is not executed.

Comment: -viewDidUnload is not called before -dealloc. This is a bad assumption that many developers make. It's only called in low memory situations.

Comment: You're wrong. Dealloc is called when you release your object from memory, e.g. When user taps 'Back' button on NavigatioBar, the ViewController receives -viewDidUnload and then -dealloc, because it's out of use. You should read more about memory management.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had any success with

`[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)]`

So instead I use

`[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id) selector:(selector) object:(id)]`

The only downside is that you must have one call to the latter for every delayed perform you have setup previously.

Hope that helps somebody. No idea why the first doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have passed nil as an argument in performSelector method and have used cancelPrevious method with self as an argument. The use of different objects in parameter is causing the problem.

use this,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(SampleMethod) withObject:self afterDelay:delayTime];
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```